# TFS Burndown AuthorizedDate

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Im looking for a way to manually adjust TFS task startdates so that my burndown appears correct.

Essentially the iteration has fixed start/end dates and some user stories did not get filled out until half way through the iteration.

This made the burndown have a bump in the road so it looks like we are below target.

I have full access to the TFS database and am wondering what queries I would need to write to get my tasks backdated to the start of the iteration.

I have read somewhere that it is System.AuthorizedDate that controls the burndown chart.

Any help appreciated.
J

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on System.AuthorizedDate being used.

You won't be able to change the System.AuthorizedDate by means of the public API. It won't let you. And you cannot change the System.AuthorizedDate date by means of SQL update commands and remain in a supported state. Officially, Microsoft does not allow this and still maintain the ability for Microsoft to support you unless the SQL enacted changes where made under their guidance such as through a support incident.

I doubt a support incident to Microsoft will yield the update query as it's not a defect and as I explain later it could put you in a very bad place. Could you create a series of updates on the appropriate tables to backdate the System.AuthorizedDate? Without doubt. It might even work but I am not certain if it would work if you dared to do so. The reason is that the work items receive System.Id numbers sequentially as created. I do know that in version control there are expectations in the system that a higher changeset number must have a later commit date (Can't recall the exact field name) than any lower changeset number. It would not surprise me if there are similar expectations in the system for work items. You might find that with such a change to the field in the work item from SQL would render errors or unexpected outcomes in various places - I can imagine a future upgrade or even an update simply bombing and unable to perform. That's all hypothetical though because unless you wish to have your environment in an unsupported state you would not change it via SQL.

Outside creating your own burndown that evaluated differently I am not aware of a means to meet your desired goal under those conditions.